# AudioQueue How to read the buffer from CallBack

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios4, audioqueue

I am Using AUdioQueue to record the audio from built-in mic and send it over socket, I have set the AudioQueue  buffer to record buffer of say 30 sec in once shot and allocating bufferSize appropriately, 
This is the function i am using to set the AudioDataFormat.

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription sRecordFormat;
 FillOutASBDForLPCM (sRecordFormat,
                    16000,
                    1,
                    16,
                    16,
                    false,
                    false
                    );
```

Following Code calculate the bufferSize that needs to be allocated to capture the audio,

```
int AQRecorder::ComputeRecordBufferSize(const AudioStreamBasicDescription *format, float seconds)
{
    int packets, frames, bytes = 0;
    try {
        frames = (int)ceil(seconds * format->mSampleRate);

        if (format->mBytesPerFrame > 0)
            bytes = frames * format->mBytesPerFrame;
        else {
            UInt32 maxPacketSize;
            if (format->mBytesPerPacket > 0)
                maxPacketSize = format->mBytesPerPacket;    // constant packet size
            else {
                UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
                XThrowIfError(AudioQueueGetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MaximumOutputPacketSize, &maxPacketSize,
                                                 &propertySize), "couldn't get queue's maximum output packet size");
            }
            if (format->mFramesPerPacket > 0)
                packets = frames / format->mFramesPerPacket;
            else
                packets = frames;   // worst-case scenario: 1 frame in a packet
            if (packets == 0)       // sanity check
                packets = 1;
            bytes = packets * maxPacketSize;
        }
    } catch (CAXException e) {
        char buf[256];
        gLog<<[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error:%s (%s)\n",e.mOperation,e.FormatError(buf)] UTF8String]<<endl;
        return 0;
    }   
    return bytes;
}
```

Following code Sample to allocate the buffer,

```
    // allocate and enqueue buffers
    bufferByteSize = ComputeRecordBufferSize(&mRecordFormat, kBufferDurationSeconds);   // enough bytes for 20 ms
    for (i = 0; i < kNumberRecordBuffers; ++i) {
        XThrowIfError(AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(mQueue, bufferByteSize, &mBuffers[i]),
                   "AudioQueueAllocateBuffer failed");
        XThrowIfError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(mQueue, mBuffers[i], 0, NULL),
                   "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
    }
```

Yes, you guessed it right, most of the code referred from SpeakHere example, 
When it comes to AudioCallback, i need to Capture the buffer and send it to other machine over socket,

```
// ____________________________________________________________________________________
// AudioQueue callback function, called when an input buffers has been filled.
void AQRecorder::MyInputBufferHandler(  void *                              inUserData,
                                        AudioQueueRef                       inAQ,
                                        AudioQueueBufferRef                 inBuffer,
                                        const AudioTimeStamp *              inStartTime,
                                        UInt32                              inNumPackets,
                                        const AudioStreamPacketDescription* inPacketDesc)
{
    AQRecorder *aqr = (AQRecorder *)inUserData;
    try {
           NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:"Inside AudioBufferCallback no of packet [%d]",inMumPackets]);
        if (inNumPackets > 0) {
            // write packets to file 
                    // This is only for the test 
            XThrowIfError(AudioFileWritePackets(aqr->mRecordFile, FALSE, inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                                              inPacketDesc, aqr->mRecordPacket, &inNumPackets, inBuffer->mAudioData),
                       "AudioFileWritePackets failed");
            aqr->mRecordPacket += inNumPackets;

            if(aqr->pInputListener){
                aqr->pInputListener(aqr->pClientUserData,inBuffer->mAudioData,(int)inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize);
            }
        }

        // if we're not stopping, re-enqueue the buffe so that it gets filled again
        if (aqr->IsRunning())
            XThrowIfError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, NULL), "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
    } 
}
```

Now when i see the log, data are coming but it says no of packets are 256, 320 like that, when i pass the data at the other end, its not audible, Can anyone tell me, what do i need to do WIth the packetSize, i was under impression to bufferSize is enough to send the data but i guess, something has got to do with the Number of Packet also.

Comment: In the Callback i am writing data in the file too, that part is working fine, only Problem is i don't understand , how to use No of packets information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problem in buffer management,
This application needs to send data in 20 ms +- 5 ms possible, in my case, this particular case was not handled.